# Using wget to download images in facebook conversations

Tags: login, wget, images, download, facebook

This looks a bit harder than usual. I'm a new `wget` user and I was thinking that maybe it's possible to login into Facebook and download  images from a specific conversation.

I mean, I'd like to tell `wget` my password and user or use cookies (I don't know how to write the line command either) and download ONLY IMAGES from a conversation.

I know that this is certainly possible. But how would I do it?

Comment: I really doubt it. I don't think `wget` or `curl` offer logging in, but even if they did, Facebook has all of this complicated confirmation stuff. i.e. you have to confirm access from a new computer.

Comment: I don't think `wget` is the right tool either. I would use the Facebook API. There are existing Perl and Python bindings for it.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) in your web-browser (also in Firefox, Opera and other), you can browse all media files in *Application* tab. To convert it into `curl` command, go to *Network* tab (*refresh* page if necessary or tick *Preserve log*), find image of your interest (list can be filtered by *Img*), right click on the request, then select [*Copy as cURL*](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference#copy). Then paste the command to the terminal.

To convert from `curl` format to `wget`, do the following conversions:

- remove `--compress` parameter,
- change `-H` to `--header` in all places.

See also:

- [How do I use wget/curl to download from a site I am logged into?](https://askubuntu.com/q/161778/78223)
- [How to download files from Facebook group?](https://superuser.com/q/1422541/87805)
- [How to download this webpage with Wget?](https://superuser.com/q/214846/87805)